# Bind XML data to a Dropdownlist c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, drop-down-menu

I am trying to bind XML data to Dropdownlist

```
 XElement xDoc = XElement.Parse(QContent.OuterXml);
```

Here is what my xDoc contains

```
<root xmlns="">
       <item value="-1" text="Select" />
       <item value="1" text="$30,000" />
       <item value="2" text="$50,000" />
    </root>
```

Query to extract the data into a Listitem :

```
 var query = from xEle in xDoc.Descendants("root")
               select new ListItem(xEle.Attribute("value").Value , xEle.Attribute("text").Value);
```

This yields no results.  Please advice.

Thanks in advance

BB

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? Can't you just create a dataset and Use the dataset to read the XML file and finally bind the dataset to the drop down list and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your LINQ query to the following which will return all the nodes under `root` and return new items with the value/text pairs that you are trying to bind to.

```
var query = from xEle in xDoc.Descendants()
select new {value = xEle.Attribute("value").Value , text = xEle.Attribute("text").Value};
```

Then set up your bindings as follows including collapsing the query to a list.

```
ddlList.DataValueField = "value";
ddlList.DataTextField = "text";
ddlList.DataSource = query.ToList();
ddlList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your XML file inside `App_Data` or anywhere in program and in `MapPath`.
Assign their path and also assign the name of your first XML column in the last line.

Here I'm using "code" because it is my first XML column and country is the name of the column I want to show in my `dropdownlist`.

```
private void BindCountry()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~//App_Data//countries.xml"));

    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//country"))
    {
        ddlcountry.Items.Add(new ListItem(node.InnerText, node.Attributes["code"].InnerText));
    }
}
```